# why does omp_get_schedule() return a monotonic schedule when OMP_SCHEDULE=static?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am compiling my code with g++8.5 on redhat8 and I notice that when I set OMP_SCHEDULE=static, then inside my application omp_get_schedule() returns a "monotonic" schedule instead of a "static" schedule. Why could this be happening? If I set OMP_SCHEDULE to something else such as "dynamic" then my application recognizes it as "dynamic". Here is the code in question. Any ideas? Thanks

```
             omp_sched_t kind;                 
             int chunk_size;
             omp_get_schedule(&kind, &chunk_size);
             
             switch(kind)
             {
               case omp_sched_static:
               {
                 schedule_msg = schedule_msg + "schedule=static, chunk_size="+std::to_string(chunk_size);
                 break;
               }
               case omp_sched_dynamic:
               {                     
                 schedule_msg = schedule_msg + "schedule=dynamic, chunk_size="+std::to_string(chunk_size);
                 break;
               }
               case omp_sched_guided:
               {
                 schedule_msg = schedule_msg + "schedule=guided, chunk_size="+std::to_string(chunk_size);                     
                 break;
               }
               case omp_sched_auto:
               {
                 schedule_msg = schedule_msg + "schedule=auto, chunk_size="+std::to_string(chunk_size);                     
                 break;
               }
               default:
               {
                 schedule_msg = schedule_msg + "schedule=monotonic, chunk_size="+std::to_string(chunk_size); 
                 break;
               }
             }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`omp_sched_t` is [defined](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu121.html) as:

```
    typedef enum omp_sched_t {
        omp_sched_static  = 1,
        omp_sched_dynamic = 2,
        omp_sched_guided  = 3,
        omp_sched_auto    = 4,
        omp_sched_monotonic = 0x80000000
    } omp_sched_t;
```

Note that `omp_sched_monotonic` is a modifier not a type, so **monotonic:static** is expressed as `omp_sched_monotonic | omp_sched_static` (and its value is `0x80000001`).

According to OpenMP standard:

> If the **static** schedule kind is specified or if the **ordered**
> clause is specified, and if no **monotonic** modifier is specified,
> the  effect will be as if the **monotonic** modifier was specified.

Therefore, if `OMP_SCHEDULE` is set to `static` the return value of `omp_get_schedule()` is `0x80000001`, but your code is not handling properly the monotonic modifier.